# How to sent push Notification to all users from firebase when new data add on Database

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to trigger database by node.js . But i did not found any solution for this problem. Once I heard to store the device token for the sending notification.But it was for the device to device sending notification.If I sent notification for all users then should i store the device token for all users??

database tree in firebase

[image]

Comment: Its not necessary that you must have fcm tokens of all the users. However, if you wish to send notification to all the users without having their fcm token then you can do it with `firebase topic messaging`. Follow this link [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) so that you may get idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send push notification to all the user without saving device token.

For this you need to add following line in `onReceive` method:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic('news');
```

Then you can send push notification to that topic, it will be sent to all the user who are registered with that topic.

**Note** : Similarly the client can unsubscribe from a topic by calling `unsubscribeFromTopic()` method.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic('news');
```